# Find the post an attachment is attached to

Tags: posts, attachments, images

I have a list of attachment IDs which are built using this array:

```
$all_images = get_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
) );
```

Is it possible to take the image ID from this list and find the Title and permalink of the POST the image is attached to?

I know it's feasible because the Media Library shows it, but I can't find the right way to do this with the codex.

I have tried this code, however it returns the title and permalink to the attachment itself, not the post it's attached to:

```
$parent = get_post_field( 'post_parent', $imgID);
$link = get_permalink($parent);
```

Comment: Googlers: $attachment->post_parent is the ID of the post that the attachment is attached to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, if you start with this:

```
$all_images = get_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
) );
```

Then `$all_images` is an array of *objects*. Step through each one:

```
foreach ( $all_images as $image ) {}
```

Inside that foreach, you can use the normal parameters available to the `$post` object:

- `$image->ID` is the ID of the attachment post
- `$image->post_parent` is the ID of the attachment post's *parent* post

So, let's use that, to get what you're after, using [`get_the_title()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) and [`get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink):

```
// Get the parent post ID
$parent_id = $image->post_parent;
// Get the parent post Title
$parent_title = get_the_title( $parent_id );
// Get the parent post permalink
$parent_permalink = get_permalink( $parent_id );
```

That's pretty much it!

Putting it all together:

```
<?php
// Get all image attachments
$all_images = get_posts( array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'numberposts' => -1,
) );
// Step through all image attachments
foreach ( $all_images as $image ) {
    // Get the parent post ID
    $parent_id = $image->post_parent;
    // Get the parent post Title
    $parent_title = get_the_title( $parent_id );
    // Get the parent post permalink
    $parent_permalink = get_permalink( $parent_id );
}
?>
```

Comment: I guess I was over thinking it. This worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

The `$images`, is an array of post objects (attachments). You can use `wp_list_pluck` to extract their parent's ID into an array. (`array_unique` and `array_filter` remove duplicate IDs and empty IDs respectively - this may /may not be desirable).

You can them loop through the IDs and use [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) and [`get_the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title) to obtain the post's permalink and title:

```
$images = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
) );
$parents = array_filter(wp_list_pluck($images,'post_parent'));
$parents = array_unique($parents);
echo "<ul>";
foreach ($parents as $id){
    echo "<li><a href='".get_permalink($id)."' >".get_the_title($id)."</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use simply https://wordpress.org/plugins/find-posts-using-attachment/

I hope it is the best way!

Comment: Explaining what the plugin does and how it answers the question would improve your answer.

Comment: This plugin adds a new column on media directory tables and all of posts that using an attachment was shown in it.