# Get title of post image is attached to

Tags: attachments, get-posts, images, get-the-title

So I found this post: [Find the post an attachment is attached to](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/find-the-post-an-attachment-is-attached-to) and implemented Chip's suggestion but having a weird outcome. I am trying to pull the title of the post that the specific image is attached to. This is my query:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'post_parent' => null,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'logo'
            )
        )
    );

    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $attachments as $image ) {
        // Get the parent post ID
        $parent_id = $image->post_parent;
        // Get the parent post Title
        $parent_title = get_the_title( $parent_id );
        // Get the parent post permalink
        $parent_permalink = get_permalink( $parent_id );
    }


    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {

            $logoimg = wp_get_attachment_image($post->ID, 'Work Gallery');
```

This is the line where I am calling the title: `echo ' ' . $parent_title . ' ';`

This kind of works but it is outputting 1 post title in particular and for all the images on the page. Any thoughts as to why its not dynamically picking up each images associated post title?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to get? The image's title? Or the title of the page it is attached to? The question at one point sounds like you want the later but at another point sounds like you are complaining that you are getting the later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This kind of works but it is outputting 1 post title in particular and for all the images on the page. Any thoughts as to why its not dynamically picking up each images associated post title?

```
$attachments = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $attachments as $image ) {

    // Get the parent post ID
    $parent_id = $image->post_parent;

    // Get the parent post Title
    $parent_title = get_the_title( $parent_id );

    // Get the parent post permalink
    $parent_permalink = get_permalink( $parent_id );
}
```

This code loops over each image. Let's debug it by hand.

As an example, let's assume there are 3 images.

The first image has a parent ID of 1, a title of "Foo" and link to that post,
The second image has a parent ID of 2, a title of "Bar" and link to that post,
The third image has a parent ID of 3, a title of "Baz" and link to that post,

So, the first time through the loop:

`$parent_id` is set to `1`,
`$parent_title` is set to `Foo`,
`$parent_permalink` is set to `the link to Foo`.

The second time through the loop:

`$parent_id` is set to `2`,
`$parent_title` is set to `Bar`,
`$parent_permalink` is set to `the link to Bar`.

All the data for the post "Foo" is overwritten with the data for post "Bar". Why? Because the code does not save that other data before writing the new data to `$parent_id`, `$parent_title` and `$parent_permalink`.

On the third trip through the loop:

`$parent_id` is set to `3`,
`$parent_title` is set to `Baz`,
`$parent_permalink` is set to `the link to Baz`.

All the data for the post "Bar" is overwritten with the data for post "Baz".

When this loop is done, the `$parent_id`, `$parent_title` and `$parent_permalink` variables only hold whatever data is in the last item of the `$attachments` array. So, the reason that only the last parent post is being used is because that is what the code told PHP to do. The code says, "Throw away those other values."

What you probably want to do is something like this:

```
$images = get_posts( $args );

if ( $images ) {

    foreach ( $images as $image ) {

        // Get the parent post ID
        $parent_id = $image->post_parent;

        // Get the parent post Title
        $parent_title = get_the_title( $parent_id );

        // Get the parent post permalink
        $parent_permalink = get_permalink( $parent_id );

        $logoimg = wp_get_attachment_image( $image->ID, 'Work Gallery' );
```

Comment: thank you for the very detailed & thorough explanation, now my images are pulling the title from the Post that they are assigned to. I guess I have one last question on this. I use this snippet on another page: `data-type="<?php $posttags = get_the_tags(); if ($posttags) { foreach ($posttags as $tag) { echo str_replace('-','_',$tag->slug . ' '); } } ?> <?php $posttags = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'type'); if ($posttags) { foreach($posttags as $tag) { echo str_replace('-','_',$tag->slug . ''); } } ?>` to get the tags from the post. Anyway to do this for these images attached post?

Comment: You're welcome and you should open another question for this new problem.