# Get the title and URL of the attachment parent post

Tags: attachments

**Goal**:
From my image.php, I am displaying the attachment image and some descriptions. I also want get the post from where it was originally posted. I only need the title and the url so that you can link back from the original post.

**Problem**:
It's not displaying the correct post title and url. Instead, it's displaying the first and last post I posted. When I change the number to "1" instead of "-1", the name just change to either the first post or the last post.

**Code**:
From this post: [Find the post an attachment is attached to](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44067/find-the-post-an-attachment-is-attached-to)

```
<?php
    // Get all image attachments
    $all_images = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    ) );
    // Step through all image attachments
    foreach ( $all_images as $image ) {
        // Get the parent post ID
        $parent_id = $image->post_parent;
        // Get the parent post Title
        $parent_title = get_the_title( $parent_id );
        // Get the parent post permalink
        $parent_permalink = get_permalink( $parent_id );
    }

    echo "This image is posted to: <a href='".$parent_permalink ."' >".$parent_title."</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All attachments has got a post parent which you can access with `$post->post_parent` inside the loop or `get_queried_object()->post_parent` outside the loop on your `image.php` or similar single post pages. (*See my question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/167706/31545) and the [answer by @gmazzap](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/167735/31545) why you should rather avoid `$post` outside the loop*)

Now that you have the post parent ID, it is easy to rewrite your function: (*CAVEAT: Untested*)

```
function get_parent_post_anchor()
{
    /*
     * Make sure we are on an attachment page, else bail and return false
     */ 
    if ( !is_attachment() )
        return false;

    /*
     * Get current attachment object
     */
    $current_attachment = get_queried_object();

    /*
     * Get the permalink of the parent
     */
    $permalink = get_permalink( $current_attachment->post_parent );

    /*
     * Get the parent title
     */
    $parent_title = get_post( $current_attachment->post_parent )->post_title;

    /*
     * Build the link
     */
    $link = '<a href="' . $permalink  . '"  title="' . $parent_title . '">' . $parent_title . '</a>';

    return $link;
}
```

You can then use it as follow

```
echo get_parent_post_anchor();
```

Comment: It outputs the name and the url of the attachment image, not the original post so it just reloads when clicking the link. Can't understand why. Any idea?

Comment: Please recheck my code, for some strange reason I used `parent` instead of `post_parent`. Sorry for stuffing you around

Comment: The edited code works like a charm. Thanks Pieter!

Comment: My pleasure. Don't know how I got mixed up here, but any way, it happens :-). Enjoy :-)